# How to programmatically determine supportedRuntime in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, configuration

I've looked through previously posted questions, and while I see related issues, I don't see the answer to the specific question I'm about to pose.

What I would like to do is programmatically determine in a PowerShell script what the supported runtimes are (especially as defined in the configuration file).  For example, if the content of my powershell.exe.config file is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
         <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319"/>        
         <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>        
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

...can I programmatically get that info from within a PowerShell script (i.e. that versions 'v4.0.30319' and 'v2.0.50727' are supported)?

Thanks in advance and apologies if this has already been answered elsewhere.

EDIT: Just to be clear, I was looking for a way that did not depend on reading the config file itself...just in case those values could be set (or defaulted) by some means other than a config file.  Is there an object I can query that contains info on the supported runtimes, regardless of how they were specified (config file or otherwise)?

Answer (score 2):

The straightforward way:

```
[xml](gc $pshome\powershell.exe.config) | 
    %{ $_.configuration.startup.supportedruntime} | 
         select -expand version
```

Comment: Sorry I probably wasn't specific enough.  I was wondering if there was a way to do this that did not rely on reading the config file itself.  The reason for doing so is in case the supported runtime versions could be defined in some other way other than the config file.

Comment: @patrick i suggest providing examples of these others ways to set the supportedruntime. I suspect most of us only know of the configuration file method.

Comment: Hi, x0n.  Honestly, I'm not even sure there are other ways to set the supported runtime.  It's more of a question of: Can I programmatically determine the supported runtimes other than looking for a config file?  (Maybe the answer is no...I'm just not sure.)  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `$PSVersionTable.CLRVersion` is what you are looking for (e.g. 2.0.50727.5420 or 4.0.30319.269). `$PSVersionTable` contains yet another useful property `PSVersion` (2.0 or 3.0). There are a few other versions there, too.